# Delphi Firemonkey DX Seattle TTabControl not reprinting correctly when inside a TVertScrollBox

Tags: delphi, tabs, firemonkey, tabcontrol, delphi-10-seattle

This was working in Delphi XE8

Here is an example project
https://github.com/dangas56/DelphiDXSeattle-BrokenTabControl

We have a VertScrollBox for when the Keyboard pops up on a device
and have multiple tabs controls and tab items to flick between screens
have noticed that the tabs sometimes don't print correctly in Delphi DX Seattle

This is an example of the code to reproduce - you can download an example from git link above

```
procedure TForm2.tbcMainChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if tbcMain.ActiveTab = tbtmSettings then
    tbcMain.TabPosition := TTabPosition.None
  else begin
    tbcMain.TabPosition := TTabPosition.Bottom;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  tbcMain.ActiveTab := tbtmHome;
end;
```

This is an example of a home screen, Clicking on the second tab sets the TabPosition to none on the origional tabControl (to hide the tabs). 
[image]

This is the second tab - normally has more tab items at the bottom
when we click on the button to go back to the original tab its setting the Tabposition of the origional tab to bottom and setting the active item to be the first tab item

[image]

As you can see below it hasn't reprinted the tab items at the bottom of the screen

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We Found a temporary Fix
instead of just setting the tabPosition from none to bottom e.g.

```
tbcMain.TabPosition := TTabPosition.Bottom;<br>
```

if you do this it seems to reprint fine again

```
tbcMain.TabPosition := TTabPosition.Bottom;
tbcMain.TabPosition := TTabPosition.Dots;
tbcMain.TabPosition := TTabPosition.Bottom;
```